# SyntaxError: invalid syntax(scanning and connect wifi)

Tags: python

I'm making a python script that scans and connect to wifi networks with a UI and now I get this error.
Why do I get this error? In which part of my code is wrong?

Here is some of my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Search Wifi and return WiFi list
    print search()
```

And here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/wifi/wifi.py", line 89
    print search()
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the python version you are using?

Comment: If you are using Python 3 use `print()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're using python 3x so print without parenthesis is wrong syntax?

just add to all the "print" commands " () " on the content you want to print- for example :

```
print(search())
```

Comment: thank you for your help:)
But now my problem moved to the library it says ImportError :(

Comment: hmmm how did you install the library itself?

Comment: by using pip install

Comment: Listen, you probably got 2 different versions of python on your computer so when you type "pip install something" it could install the package to the python that you're not using. Please run on cmd/terminal pip --version and see if it returns 2.7 or 3x if it returns 2.7 run "pip3 install whatever" for the package you want and it will fix your error (:

Comment: You really helped me a lot :)